# Error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" en java

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas,

Al insertar o actualizar datos en MySQL desde java me sale el error comentado. No sé a qué se debe, el número de columnas es correcto...de hecho antes tenía el mismo código pero con menos columnas, no entiendo dónde puede estar el problema.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public Conectate(ArrayList<Item> games, final Map<String, String> countries) {    

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


        //CREAMOS LA TABLA
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), "
                + "Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), Juego VARCHAR(500), Tipologia VARCHAR (500), Pertenece VARCHAR (500), "
                + "Nota VARCHAR (10), Descripcion_Ingles TEXT(4000), Descripcion_Castellano TEXT(4000), Pegi VARCHAR(10), Pegi_USA VARCHAR (30) , Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR(500), Codigo_juego VARCHAR (100),"
                + "Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50), URL VARCHAR (400),"
                        + "Argentina VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Gold VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Australia VARCHAR (50), Australia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Australia_Gold VARCHAR (50), Australia_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Brasil VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Gold VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Canada VARCHAR (50), Canada_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Canada_Gold VARCHAR (50), Canada_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Chile VARCHAR (50), Chile_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Chile_Gold VARCHAR (50), Chile_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "China VARCHAR (50), China_Oferta VARCHAR (50), China_Gold VARCHAR (50), China_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Colombia VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Gold VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Espanya VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Gold VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "USA VARCHAR (50), USA_Oferta VARCHAR (50), USA_Gold VARCHAR (50), USA_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Hong_Kong VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Gold VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Hungria VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Gold VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "India VARCHAR (50), India_Oferta VARCHAR (50), India_Gold VARCHAR (50), India_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Inglaterra VARCHAR (50), Inglaterra_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Inglaterra_Gold VARCHAR (50), Inglaterra_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Japon VARCHAR (50), Japon_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Japon_Gold VARCHAR (50), Japon_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Korea VARCHAR (50), Korea_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Korea_Gold VARCHAR (50), Korea_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Mexico VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Gold VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Rusia VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Gold VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Access VARCHAR (50),"                 
                        + "Singapur VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Gold VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Access VARCHAR (50),"                            
                        + "Sudafrica VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Gold VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Access VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Taiwan VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Gold VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Access VARCHAR (50)"

                + ")");              

        System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");            

        for (Item game : games) {
            String titulo = game.getName();

            boolean isInsert;
            try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?")) {
                ps.setString(1, titulo);

                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    isInsert = !rs.next();
                }
            }

            if (isInsert) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
                try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi,Pegi_USA, Descripcion_Pegi, Codigo_juego, URL,"
                        + "Argentina, Argentina_Oferta, Argentina_Gold, Argentina_Access,"
                        + "Australia, Australia_Oferta, Australia_Gold, Australia_Access,"
                        + "Brasil, Brasil_Oferta, Brasil_Gold, Brasil_Access,"
                        + "Canada, Canada_Oferta, Canada_Gold, Canada_Access,"
                        + "Chile, Chile_Oferta, Chile_Gold, Chile_Access,"
                        + "China, China_Oferta, China_Gold, China_Access,"
                        + "Colombia, Colombia_Oferta, Colombia_Access,"
                        + "Espanya, Espanya_Oferta, Espanya_Gold, Colombia_Access,"
                        + "USA, USA_Oferta, USA_Gold, USA_Access,"
                        + "Hong_Kong, Hong_Kong_Oferta, Hong_Kong_Gold, Hong_Kong_Access,"
                        + "Hungria, Hungria_Oferta, Hungria_Gold, Hungria_Access,"
                        + "India, India_Oferta, India_Gold, India_Access,"
                        + "Inglaterra, Inglaterra_Oferta, Inglaterra_Gold, Inglaterra_Access,"
                        + "Japon, Japon_Oferta, Japon_Gold, Japon_Access,"
                        + "Korea, Korea_Oferta, Korea_Gold, Korea_Access,"
                        + "Mexico, Mexico_Oferta, Mexico_Gold, Mexico_Access,"
                        + "Rusia, Rusia_Oferta, Rusia_Gold, Rusia_Access,"                 
                        + "Singapur, Singapur_Oferta, Singapur_Gold, Singapur_Access,"                            
                        + "Sudafrica, Sudafrica_Oferta, Sudafrica_Gold, Sudafrica_Access,"
                        + "Taiwan, Taiwan_Oferta, Taiwan_Gold, Taiwan_Access"                           
                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"                           
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ")")) {

                    ps.setString(1,titulo);
                    ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                    ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                    ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                    ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                    ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                    ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                    ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                    ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));   
                    ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL)); 
                    ps.setString(11,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_JUEGO));
                    int contador = 12;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_ACCESS + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                    }
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            } else {
                String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET Tipologia = ?, Pertenece = ?, "
                + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
                + "Pegi = ?, Pegi_USA = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ?, juego = ?, URL = ?,"
                        + "Argentina = ?, Argentina_Oferta = ?, Argentina_Gold = ?, Argentina_Access = ?,"
                        + "Australia = ?, Australia_Oferta = ?, Australia_Gold = ?, Australia_Access = ?,"
                        + "Brasil = ?, Brasil_Oferta = ?, Brasil_Gold = ?, Brasil_Access = ?,"
                        + "Canada = ?, Canada_Oferta = ?, Canada_Gold = ?, Canada_Access = ?,"
                        + "Chile = ?, Chile_Oferta = ?, Chile_Gold = ?, Chile_Access = ?,"
                        + "China = ?, China_Oferta = ?, China_Gold = ?, China_Access = ?,"
                        + "Colombia = ?, Colombia_Oferta = ?, Colombia_Gold = ?, Colombia_Access = ?,"
                        + "Espanya = ?, Espanya_Oferta = ?, Espanya_Gold = ?, Espanya_Access = ?,"
                        + "USA = ?, USA_Oferta = ?, USA_Gold = ?, USA_Access = ?,"
                        + "Hong_Kong = ?, Hong_Kong_Oferta = ?, Hong_Kong_Gold = ?, Hong_Kong_Access = ?,"
                        + "Hungria = ?, Hungria_Oferta = ?, Hungria_Gold = ?, Hungria_Access = ?,"
                        + "India = ?, India_Oferta = ?, India_Gold = ?, India_Access = ?,"
                        + "Inglaterra = ?, Inglaterra_Oferta = ?, Inglaterra_Gold = ?, Inglaterra_Access = ?,"
                        + "Japon = ?, Japon_Oferta = ?, Japon_Gold = ?, Japon_Access = ?,"
                        + "Korea = ?, Korea_Oferta = ?, Korea_Gold = ?, Korea_Access = ?,"
                        + "Mexico = ?, Mexico_Oferta = ?, Mexico_Gold = ?, Mexico_Access = ?,"
                        + "Rusia = ?, Rusia_Oferta = ?, Rusia_Gold = ?, Rusia_Access = ?,"                 
                        + "Singapur = ?, Singapur_Oferta = ?, Singapur_Gold = ?, Singapur_Access = ?,"                            
                        + "Sudafrica = ?, Sudafrica_Oferta = ?, Sudafrica_Gold = ?, Sudafrica_Access = ?,"
                        + "Taiwan = ?, Taiwan_Oferta = ?, Taiwan_Gold = ?, Taiwan_Access = ?"                           
                        + " WHERE Codigo_juego = ?";

                try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                    ps.setString(1,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                    ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                    ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                    ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                    ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                    ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                    ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                    ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                    ps.setString(9,titulo);
                    ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_JUEGO));
                    ps.setString(91,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL));
                    int contador = 11;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_ACCESS + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                    }
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }           
}


} catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, por lo que veo, la cantidad de tus datos insertados son 91 y el de preparados también es 914, por ese lado no hay problemas. Pero fijate en esta parte de tu código del preparedStatement para el Insert:

```
+ "China, China_Oferta, China_Gold, China_Access,"
+ "Colombia, Colombia_Oferta, Colombia_Access,"
+ "Espanya, Espanya_Oferta, Espanya_Gold, Colombia_Access,"
```

Primero, veo que te faltó la columna Colombia_Gold. Segundo, tenes duplicado Colombia_Access, uno de ellos debe ser Espanya_Access

Comment: Vaya ojo, mira que lo he revisado unas cuantas veces, incluidas las comas, que era lago que me venía fallando normalmente, y no había caído. Voy a probar de nuevo ejecutando el programa a ver si se resuelve el problema, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Suele pasar, y más todavía cuando hay muchas columnas que procesar

Comment: @JetLagFox ¿Por qué no separas tus tablas y consultas tus datos haciendo JOIN? Creo que un diseño tan repetitivo es problemático y termina siendo lento.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que esté interpretando la indicación que le haces de `PRIMARY KEY`como otra columna de la tabla:

En vez de:

<s>st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), ...</s>

Prueba algo así:

```
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), ...
```

Y, por depurar más cosas:

Agregaría un `;`al final de la instrucción SQL:

```
...   + "Taiwan VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Gold VARCHAR (50), Taiwan_Access VARCHAR (50)"
                + ");");  
                    ^  aquí
```

Si no es eso, alguna coma de más o de menos, o algún signo `+`de más o de menos o algún `(` o `)`de más o de menos.